# Why won't my replaced GFCI outlet power something plugged into it?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I have a string of outlets that was not working. I replaced the most upstream outlet GFCI with another GFCI. I also replaced some weathered outdoor outlets.

Currently the GFCI is green and does send power downstream. So every outlet downstream can power a load.

The GFCI when I plug something into is unable to power a load.

What did I miss?

Comment: Is the GFCI tripping? How did you wire the down stream receptacles?  Another GFCI? Do you have more than 1 GFCI in this string that can make resetting and testing problematic.

Comment: When you plug into the GFCI does it trip, or just no power? Also, you should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how to participate here.

Comment: The GFCI isnt tripping. Only 1 GFCI in the string and its most upstream.

Comment: Maybe turn off the breaker, pull each outlet and get a pic inside the box and of the back of each outlet. Post them, carefully labeled and in order from closest to breaker to the end of the line. This will help the licensed electricians here help you sort out what's going on.

Comment: Also, I tried to make your title more explicit so people know what they're getting into before they even click the link. Please review the edit to ensure I've got it right. If not, feel free to [edit] again and reword the title to better summarize the issue (in one short question).

Comment: Did you remove the warning tape covering the LOAD terminals?  Did you attach some wires to LINE and some to LOAD, or all to LINE?  Or all to LOAD?